# crontab not executing oracle database image copy

Tags: oracle

Dears i have an rman script for a full Oracle Database Image Copy that i have made and i have added it to a crontab job and buts it is not getting executed and i dont know why: below is the database image backup script:

```
RMANBACKUP_MOUNTPOINT1=/home/rmanbackups/uvc_imagebackup/
export ORACLE_HOME=/oracle/app/product/11gR2/db
export ORACLE_SID=ora11g
export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH

fullBackup () {
rman log=/home/rmanbackups/uvc_imagebackup/rman_imagecopy.log << EOF
connect target /
set echo on;
configure backup optimization on;
run
{
BACKUP AS COPY DATABASE TAG 'IMAGE COPY';
}
configure backup optimization clear;
exit
EOF
}

fullBackup
```

Below is the crontab script:

```
30 15 * * * "/home/rmanbackups/uvc_imagebackup/uvc_image_bkp.sh" > /home/rmanbackups/uvc_imagebackup/cron_imagecopy.log
```

Comment: "not working" conveys no actionable information.  Surely you get some error messages?  The most common reason for 'it works manually but not with crontab' is because jobs submitted with crontab don't get the environment set up from .bash_profile.  The script needs to take responsibility for setting all necessary environment variables.  Like, oh, say ORACLE_HOME, PATH (including ORACLE_HOME/bin), ORACLE_SID.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your script is missing the `#!` line
2. The `"` in your crontab file bothers me
3. The script is probably not executable (r-x permissions)
4. It is unclear who is running the script and if the account can connect as such

   - can this user login without a password?
   - are you using an Oracle Wallet so you don't need to keep the name/password in plain text in the script?
5. Modifications to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` might be needed

   - try using `/usr/local/bin/oraenv` instead